# populate combobox with values from another form

Tags: c#, sql-server, combobox

I might ask a stupid question, but I can't find it on the internet.

I have a combobox and I would like to retrieve some data from another form where the info is typed and saved by the user. If anyone is willing to help, I'll be greatful. Thanks

I used this code

```
 string cs = "Data Source=CODRINMA\\CODRINMA;Initial Catalog=BusManager; Trusted_Connection=True;";
            string select = "SELECT * FROM TipAutocar";

            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(select, con);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    cmbTip.Items.Add(dr["Model", "Type"]);
                }
                con.Close();
```

And it worked..but is this possible to get for eg "Model" + "Type"?

And I get this error ->

> Error 1   No overload for method 'this' takes 2 arguments

Comment: Well. Let's asume this: on the Form1 i have the combo "Model" and also i have a Form2 called "Model" in which the user complete the info about a model and save it. I would like that, when i'm on the Form1 and click on that combo, to get all the models have been saved by the user. Don't know if what you have answered works, 'cause i haven't tried. Will it work your code? Thanks

Comment: Those forms are beeing open at the same time or clicking save on one form is opening the second one ?

Comment: No. On the Form2 the user complete some information about a product. On the Form1, I would like to get all that info when I open the combo. Hope i was clear now..

Comment: I asked You the question "Something or Something" and Your answer is no ... Paste some code so I'll then maybe understand

Comment: not in the comment - edit your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to add different column values to your `ComboBox` concatenated. So, it's as simple as that:

```
while (dr.Read())
    {
      cmbTip.Items.Add(dr["Model"].ToString() + " " + dr["Type"].ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Mike Debela. This was exactly what I wanted.